# Ford Fiesta 2010 - Vents Only working on face blowers

Tags: ford, fiesta

I have a Ford Fiesta Titanium 2010[image].

I have a problem with my dash blowers. The air only out from the front face blowers.

The only thing that blows is the front face blowers. All other climate controls work such as the blower speed, temperature and air conditioning.

Can anyone share some light on what the issue may be? I have searched many forums and cannot find a solution.

In the picture, I have circled the controls that are not working in a red circle and the green circle the one that is working

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Could be a few things really... Underneath the dash there will be a fan and type of air box chamber with ducting pipes that go off to their respective vents. The air flow through these ducts is normally directed by flaps that open and close depending on which vents you choose to have air flowing from.

Its possible that there could be a hose come adrift or a failed plastic pin or lever etc that's causing the issue. However as newer vehicles use actuators/servo motors etc to control the flaps it's likely that one of these has failed or there is a wiring/control unit issue.

You'd first need to do a visual underneath the dash in the footwells, just to see if anything obvious had happened mechanically, like something becoming detached or broken etc.
Following that though it would then be a case of plugging in a fault code diagnostic tool to see if there were any fault codes being generated, and if so go from there to further determine the issue.